# Method getPhpcrSession class ObjectManager

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-cmf

So I don't have getPhpcrSession method in ObjectManager from where I am trying to get this method. I have found it in [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/tutorials/using_blockbundle_and_contentbundle.html)
And I need it so that I could implement Block and Content Bundles.
I have found on the Net original ObjectManager class and it looks like [this](https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/ObjectManager.php). Providing me with some documentation or providing me with an answer would be cool. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to look at the DocumentManager of phpcr-odm which is in this github project: https://github.com/doctrine/phpcr-odm/

the interface of fixture is using the base commons ObjectManager which is extended by orm / phpcr-odm and the others. this is why you don't see type hints if you use an IDE. but what you get there should be instanceof Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\DocumentManager

if you want to use this with doctrine ORM, you would have to provide mappings for the Documents and probably some other work. we are currently working on that feature so it will come.